# django-registration - NoReverseMatch at /accounts/login/at /accounts/login/

Tags: python, django, django-1.6

Trying to make django-registration work within the Django Tutorial polls projects.

I'm using Django 1.6, django-registration 1.0 and the [django-registration-templates](https://github.com/macdhuibh/django-registration-templates)

When I try to access

```
http://localhost:8000/accounts/login/
```

I get

```
NoReverseMatch at /accounts/login/

Reverse for 'index' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

The line in the template, mysite/templates/base.html, that's cited in the error report is :

```
<a href="{% url 'index' %}">{% trans "Home" %}</a> |
```

And I do have a url with name 'index' in my polls.url :

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/results/$', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
)
```

So I feel like that should work ? Help ?

---

***EDIT 1***

**polls.urls:**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from polls import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/results/$', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
)
```

**mysite.urls:**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls', namespace="polls")),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
)
```

**registration.urls:**

```
"""
Backwards-compatible URLconf for existing django-registration
installs; this allows the standard ``include('registration.urls')`` to
continue working, but that usage is deprecated and will be removed for
django-registration 1.0. For new installs, use
``include('registration.backends.default.urls')``.

"""

import warnings

warnings.warn("include('registration.urls') is deprecated; use include('registration.backends.default.urls') instead.",
              DeprecationWarning)

from registration.backends.default.urls import *
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK I've figured out the problem here. The url with name 'index' was defined in polls.urls and so within the template I needed to change :

```
<a href="{% url 'index' %}">{% trans "Home" %}</a>
```

to

```
<a href="{% url 'polls:index' %}">{% trans "Home" %}</a>
```

As mentioned in the [Django 1.6 documention of the url tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#std%3atemplatetag-url) and which I quote here for convenience :

> If you’d like to retrieve a namespaced URL, specify the fully
>   qualified name:
>
> {% url 'myapp:view-name' %}
>
> This will follow the normal namespaced URL resolution strategy,
>   including using any hints provided by the context as to the current
>   application.